# Removing UISearchController from UINavigationBar when inactive

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a `UISearchController` when a button is pressed to the `UINavigationBar`.  Then when the button is pressed again, it dismisses the searchbar.  So far I have:

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if searchController == nil {
        var resultsController = SearchResultsViewController()
        resultsController.searchResultsDelegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController

        searchController!.searchBar.frame = CGRect(
            x: searchController!.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
            y: searchController!.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
            width: searchController!.searchBar.frame.size.width,
            height: 44.0)
        searchController!.searchBar.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }

    if !searchBarActive {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.searchController!.searchBar.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil)
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Default
        searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.searchController!.searchBar.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) // edited: tried this per comments but also does not work
        searchController!.active = false
    }

    searchBarActive = !searchBarActive
}
```

This does add the `searchController.searchBar` and slide it in from the RHS of the screen.  When the button is pressed again, it does slide the search bar back off to the right.  However, my back button that was covered by the search bar doesn't get reset to say the words "Back, and the original `navitionItem`.title that was there also does not come back when I slide the `searchBar` off screen.  I feel like I'm missing something in order to dismiss the `searchController`, but I don't know what the right call is.  The `searchController`.active property does not seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` to dismiss the `UISearchController` and perform all other changes in the completion block of the method.